# how to divs at bottom of screen and inline and overlapping parent div

Tags: html, css

how do i make divs display at the bottom of the screen inline (following each other horizontally like facebook chat) and also overlapping their parent div. i have tried the following but does not work.

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="box">
   </div>
   <div id="box">
   </div>
   <div id="box">
   </div>
</div>

#container{
   height:10px;
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   width:1000px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
#box{
   border:1px solid blue;
   width:250px;
   height:300px;
   display:inline-table;
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Can u tell me ur target html,what do u want ????

Comment: You cannot have more than one ID defined on the page.  IDs must be unique.

Comment: Use `class="box"` instead and reference it in CSS using `.box { }`

Comment: i am new to this. for give me. should i use class instead?

Comment: that was not concern with ID,He give all Position to fixed and he didn't insert any items within div tags, so He can't see them too

Comment: i want the divs in the parent div to be at the bottom of the screen and not clamped together like i have here but should follow in a line (from left to right or right to left)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QDpp8/  that was my test area.I don't know what u mean exactly .Pls check that

Comment: if had ever had conversation with two or more persons on face book, then that is a typical example of what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the elements in another container div, which is positioned absolutely.

Firstly, you can't use duplicate id's. Use classes instead.

Your HTML will be something like:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
     </div>        
 </div>
```

You can't use display:inline-table and fixed together. Use position:absolute or position:fixed (if you want to make the items stick) for the container div, and for instance display:inline-block for the .box elements to get them inline.

```
#container {
   height:10px;
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   width:1000px;
   margin:0 auto;
}

.box-container {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
}

.box{
   border:1px solid blue;
   width:250px;
   height:40px;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/B228U/1/ for an example.

Cheers,

Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

You can´t give same id to different elements. Use class. Also give main div position:relative and float:left to rhe class box. Like this:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="box">
   </div>
   <div class="box">
   </div>
   <div class="box">
   </div>
</div>


#container{
   height:10px;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:1000px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
.box{
   border:1px solid blue;
   width:250px;
   height:300px;
   float:left;
   display:inline-table;
   position:relative;
   bottom:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7kwLc/